# Automatically choose delete worksheet without message popping up

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote vba code to delete a sheet permanently. When i run it, comes up with the following message:

"Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion. To permanently delete the data, press Delete."

How can i write this code so that it deletes the worksheet automatically without the message popping up?

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SVT").Delete
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SVT").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution, since it's using global state to manage a local problem, but it's probably the only way to do it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx

Comment: A slightly more idempotent solution might involve restoring the previous value of the `DisplayAlerts` property, which might not have been `True` beforehand.